# WebStorm file watcher output to wrong file

Tags: pug, webstorm, mean-stack

For example when I update my layout.jade file index.html gets updated with that output...

here are my file watcher settings
http://screencast.com/t/qFUeqPb9VzhC

here are my files and outputs
http://screencast.com/t/GElo7LF3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `block content` in your layout.jade file. File watchers work correctly.

See [Template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade-language.md#template-inheritance) reference in Jade documentation.